# Fieldset in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How to set fieldset in python tkinter as shown here: [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by _fieldset_? Entry widget? Please also see, [MCVE]

Comment: Do you mean [LabelFrame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm) ? Or you need `grid()` with `Frame()` to organize in columns/rows.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a frame and put widgets in it?

Comment: this same thing is called fieldset in html forms @Lafexlos

Answer (score 1):

In tkinter fieldset is called `LabelFrame()`.

So do this

```
fieldset = LabelFrame(root, text="")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is designed to help you create your interface. I have started to add some of the data as a demonstration but haven't finished it because you know exactly how you want it.

To add more objects, add to the 'Information' list like this for a rectangle:

```
[0, ((Top left x coordinate, top left y coordinate), (Bottom right x coordinate, bottom right y coordinate))]
```

For a text label:

```
[1, (Top left x coordinate, top left y coordinate), text to be displayed]
```

For a text entry:

```
[2, (Top left x coordinate, top left y coordinate), default text (put "" for no text)]
```

Final code:

```
window_width = 400
window_height = 500
window_title = "Order System"
Information = [[0, ((10, 15), (200, 100))], [1, (20, 5), "Bill To"],
               [1, (15, 40), "Name:"], [2, (60, 40), ""]]
from tkinter import *
root = Tk ()
root.title (window_title)
Entries = []
c = Canvas (root, width = window_width, height = window_height, bg = "white")
c.pack ()
for x in range (len (Information)):
    if Information [x] [0] == 0:
        c.create_rectangle (Information [x] [1])
    elif Information [x] [0] == 1:
        c.create_window (Information [x] [1], anchor = NW, window = Label (root, text = Information [x] [2], bg = "white"))
    elif Information [x] [0] == 2:
        Entries.append (Entry (root))
        Entries [len (Entries) - 1].insert (END, Information [x] [2])
        c.create_window (Information [x] [1], anchor = NW, window = Entries [len (Entries) - 1])
    else:
        print ("There is no method for " + type [x])
root.mainloop ()
```

Answer (score 0):

In tkinter fieldset is called **LabelFrame()**. Using the text property of LabelFrame you can set the label, just like that:

```
fieldset = LabelFrame(root, text="Here goes the label")
```

Here you can find more info and examples of [LabelFrame()](https://www.studytonight.com/tkinter/python-tkinter-labelframe-widget).